# How to make my character slide (not bounce) off a slope

Tags: collision-detection, mathematics

My character needs to slide and not bounce off a slope.

The solutions I found here use a Reflection vector, but they make my character bouncy when they run downwards a slope.

```
var reflectVector = normal.clone().multiplyScalar(-this.velocity.clone().dot(normal));
this.velocity.addSelf(reflectVector);
```

How can I make my character simply stick to the terrain when they walk? 
[image: How to calculate the desired velocity]

Comment: Use Box2D and set the body's restitution to 0.

Comment: Using 3D :P but I drew this diagram to make it more easy to understand. Thanks though

Comment: How about use bulletphysics and set the restitution to 0? PS. I like physics engines.

Comment: @ClassicThunder Suggesting a physics engine for a simple vector math problem is an overkill. It's good to learn the math first. Of course it's good to learn physics engines as well, but I wouldn't go that far yet.

Comment: @msell "a simple vector math problem" Its never just 1 simple vector math problem. Anyways it was just a reminder that he is reinventing the wheel.

Comment: It's allways good to reinvent the whell if you wanna learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eliminate the normal component from the old velocity using vector projection to get the desired velocity. Assuming normal is a unit vector, the formula is:

```
desiredVelocity = oldVelocity - dot(normal, oldVelocity) * normal;
```

Applying gravity should accelerate the desired velocity, or if you just want constant speed, normalize it and scale as you wish.

You can also think this as a case of reflection. Reflection is `oldVelocity - 2 * dot(normal, oldVelocity) * normal;`. Here 2 can be replaced with (1 + e), where e is elasticy in the range [0, 1]. With 1 you get the perfect reflection and with 0 you get the formula above with your desired result. With a value between 0 and 1 you get small bounce.

Answer (score 2):

here is pseudo code of one way it can be accomplished.

```
float speed = oldVelocity.Length();
tempVector = cross(oldVelocity, normal);
desiredVelocity = cross(normal, tempVector);
desiredVelocity.normalize();
desiredVelocity *= speed;
```